# Expressing PropertyisNull = true/false in a Spring Data QueryMethod

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In more detail:

Is there a way to express the following JPQL in a Spring Data JPA query method with a boolean parameter "propertyIsNull":

```
Select entity where ( propertyToCheckForNull is null ) = :propertyIsNull
```

i.e. like similar to the following:

```
fun findAll...AndByPropertyToCheckForNullIsNullIs(
    propertyIsNull: Boolean
): Set<MyEntity>
```

?

If not possible, what would be the best work-around?
Side-conditions:

- no JPQL (or even SQL)
- no Hibernate @Formula
- keep query semantics (i.e. I definitely want a boolean parameter ('propertyIsNull') to control this)
- lean, because I have several query methods, that, among several other conditions,
  contain the propertyIsNull parameter

I am thinking about something like this

- clever method parameter transformation within the JPA query method (signature) (I am using Kotlin). I would like to avoid having to define secondary query methods.
- some Entity annotation magic (however, must work with a @SecondaryTable as the 'propertyIsNull' is from a secondary table)
- additional properties on the entity

Thanks!

Here is a POC Enity:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "secondaryEntitySource")
class MyEntity(
  @Id
  val id: String? = null
  ...
){
   @Column(name = "id", table = "secondaryEntitySource", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   val propertyToCheckForNull : String? = null
   ...
}

/**
```